# When I try to send email via SendGrid, I get error "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, sendgrid

I created a SendGrid account via Azure. The thing is that the sending e-mails via localhost works well. But when I deploy my asp.net mvc project to my server, I get this error.

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

My SendEmail() method is like this:

```
    public static async Task<bool> SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject,
        string callbackUrl, string Name, string sendingType,
        string replyToEmail = "info@example.com", string replyToName = "Example Company", string fromName = "Example Company")
    {
        string html = "";
        if (sendingType == "1")
        {
            html = string.Format("some html code for email is here", Name, callbackUrl, callbackUrl);
        }
        else if (sendingType == "2")
        {
            html = string.Format("some html code for email is here", Name, callbackUrl, callbackUrl);
        }
        else if (sendingType == "3")
        {
            html = string.Format("some html code for email is here", Name, callbackUrl, callbackUrl);
        }
        else if (sendingType == "4")
        {
            html = string.Format("some html code for email is here", Name, callbackUrl, callbackUrl);
        }
        else if (sendingType == "5")
        {
            html = string.Format("some html code for email is here", callbackUrl);
        }

        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        
        if (sendingType == "5")
        {
            IEnumerable<string> emailAddresses = toEmail.Split(',');
            myMessage.AddTo("info@example.com");
            foreach (var item in emailAddresses)
            {
                myMessage.AddBcc(item);
            }
            //myMessage.AddTo(emailAddresses);
        }
        else
        {
            myMessage.AddTo(toEmail);
        }
        myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(
                            "info@example.com", "example company");
        myMessage.Subject = subject;
        //myMessage.Text = message.Body;
        myMessage.Html = html;

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
                   );

        // Create a Web transport for sending email.
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        // Send the email.
        if (transportWeb != null)
        {
            try
            {
                await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
                transportWeb = null;
                myMessage = null;
            }
            catch (InvalidApiRequestException ex)
            {
                var detalle = new StringBuilder();

                detalle.Append("ResponseStatusCode: " + ex.ResponseStatusCode + ".   ");
                for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count(); i++)
                {
                    detalle.Append(" -- Error #" + i.ToString() + " : " + ex.Errors[i]);
                }

                throw new ApplicationException(detalle.ToString(), ex);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
            await Task.FromResult(0);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I saw some comments for this error, and I wrote transportWeb = null; myMessage = null; after DeliverAsync method. But it didn't work again.

My web.config is like this.

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="mailAccount" value="azure_xxxxxxx@azure.com" />
    <add key="mailPassword" value="password" />
  </appSettings>
<!-- just in case I write system.net as well -->
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false">
      <proxy/>
      <bypasslist/>
      <module/>
    </defaultProxy>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="azure_xxxxxxxx@azure.com">
        <network host="smtp.sendgrid.net" port="587" userName="xxxxx@azure.com" password="password" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Full error and stack trace is like this

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +6601895
   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +56

[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.]
   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +230
   System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +119

[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) +316
   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +107

[HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   SendGrid.<DeliverAsync>d__7.MoveNext() +405
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   AdventureBus.Logic.<SendEmail>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Users\tahameral\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AdvantureBus\AdventureBus.Logic\EmailHelper.cs:213
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   AdventureBus.Logic.<SendSpecialMail>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\tahameral\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AdvantureBus\AdventureBus.Logic\EmailHelper.cs:43
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Basvuru.AdventureBus.Areas.Admin.Controllers.<Send>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\tahameral\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AdvantureBus\Basvuru.AdventureBus\Areas\Admin\Controllers\AdminMailController.cs:35
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

My project pattern is like this:

xxxx.Data: which has repositories, entity data model, models etc.

xxxx.Logic: which has EmailHelper, DropdownListHelper, etc.

xxxx: which has MVC project

When you look at the Stack Trace, you can see the project path which is "C:\Users\tahameral\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AdvantureBus\AdventureBus.Logic\EmailHelper.cs:213".

I don't understand why that path shows on there. But just in case, I tried to copy EmailHelper.cs into the MVC project, I changed the namespance and I called this EmailHelper. But the error still was there.

Comment: Could you try a different port besides 587? Something like 25, or 2525, for unencrypted, or 465 for TLS connections https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/Email_Infrastructure/recommended_smtp_settings.html

Comment: Hi Andrés, thanks for your comment. Well, I decided to send email synchronous, and I'm now using MailMessage and SmtpClient instead of using SendGrid helper..